# Discord.py differentiating between two different servers

Tags: python-3.x, client, discord.py

I would like to ask about deploying a bot in 2 different servers. Is there any way to differentiate the two bot instances? For example, I would like to run a bot for serverA and another instance of the same bot in serverB (testing server). I would like to have it so that the bot would respond to a command like "!ping" only once in serverB when testing even if serverA and serverB both have running instances of my bot (meaning there are 2 different running scripts of the same code). My dilemma is that if I have two of the same code running in 2 different terminals, when I try to call for !ping command in serverB, it performs the action twice since there are 2 instances.

Comment: You'll have to create two different bot accounts on Discord and use the separate tokens for the two instances

Answer (score 0):

Running a bot in 2 terminals is not the same as having your bot join 2 servers. You'll only have 1 instance of the bot running but it's basically listening to both servers.

Differentiating between different servers is generally not needed because the bot will be responding in the context of the server it got a command from. However, if you want to keep track of certain data with files you can do so by including the server name in the file name. This way you can store data for each server separately.